# Java stream - delete everything after first match

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a linked hash list of some DTO that contains name (String) and isActive (boolean) properties. I need to iterate over all of them from first to last and check, if any of members have false value in isActive. When I find this element, I need to cut off this element and the rest of list and return just elements before this one.

I would like to use java streams to solve this problem.
I've tried to use stream and filter elements via predicate to check if element is active but that does not match the logic I want. As I said, I need to find first element that is inActive and cut it and everything after from the list.

If we have this list of ElementDto in LinkedHashSet<>

```
0 - name:test, isActive:true
1 - name:test2, isActive:true
2 - name:inActive, isActive:false
3 - name:activeAfterInactive, isActive:true
```

The expected output would be list with elements 0,1

Comment: Is this not just `Stream.takeWhile(Element::isActive())`?

Comment: What is a “linked hash list”?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following should work for any ordered collection:

```
elementCollection.stream().takeWhile(el -> el.isActive())...
```

Comment: it's work only from java9. Maybe any for j8?

Comment: Java9 was released nearly 4 years ago and Java11 is LTS. Giving solutions for older versions seems unnecessary at this point.